# How to have have multiple mat-selects each with a different font color for the selected value?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'd like to have multiple mat-selects on a page, each with a different color for the mat-select-value.

When I put this in my css it changes the color of all the selected values:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-select-value {
    color: green !important;
}
```

I want another mat-select that has a mat-select-value of blue though.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<mat-select class="blue">` then

```
:host ::ng-deep .blue .mat-select-value {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

And so on..

Comment: Thank you, this works.  I tried something like this, but didn't quite know the exact syntax.